# Correct way to create Pytorch dataset that returns sequence of data for RNN?

Tags: python, deep-learning, dataset, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am attempting to train an RNN on time series data, and while there are plenty of tutorials out there on how to build a RNN model I am having some trouble with building the dataloader object for this task. The data is all going to be the same length, so no need for padding as well. The approach I have taken so far is to return a range of data in the **getitem** function on the dataset class and define the length as

```
len(data) - seq_len + 1
```

, however I feel that this is a bit "hacky" and that there should be a more proper way to do this. This method seems confusing and I feel that this would cause problems if collaborating with a group. More specifically, I think that somehow overriding the sampler function in the Pytorch Dataset constructor is the correct way, but I am having trouble understanding how to implement that. Below is the current dataset class I have built, can anyone point me in the right direction with how to fix it? Thank you in advance.

```
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, df, cats, y, seq_l):
    self.n, self.seq_l = len(df), seq_l
    self.cats  = np.array(np.stack([c.values for n,c in df[cats].items()], 1).astype(np.int64))
    self.conts = np.array(np.stack([c.values for n,c in df[[i for i in df.columns if i not in cats]].items()], 1).astype(np.float32))
    self.y = np.array(y)

  def __len__(self): return len(self.y) - self.seq_l + 1

  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    return [
      (torch.from_numpy(self.cats[idx:idx+self.seq_l]),
      torch.from_numpy(self.conts[idx:idx+self.seq_l])),
      self.y[idx+self.seq_l-1]
    ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly you have time series data and you want to crate batches of data with the same length by sampling from it?
I think you can use **Dataset** for returning just one sample of data as it was initially intended by the PyTorch developers. You can stack them in the batch with your own **_collate_fn** function and pass it to the DataLoader class (_collate_fn is a callable which takes a list of samples and returns a batch, usually, for example, padding is done there). So you would not have a dependency of length (=batch size in your dataset class). I assume you want to preserve sequential order of your samples when you form a batch (given that you work with time series), you can write your own **Sampler** class (or use SequentialSampler already available in PyTorch).
As a result, you will decouple your sample representation, forming them in a batch (_collate_fn in DataLoader) and sampling (Sampler class). Hope this helps.

Comment: `collate_fn (callable, optional) – merges a list of samples to form a mini-batch.` Wow looks like I missed that somehow, yes this all makes perfect sense and seems to be implemented the way it was meant to by the Pytorch developers. Thank you!